# taking input from html input in secure way in laravel withoit using facade

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, laravel-5.3

i have a html form in laravel based project. this html form insert data to database table called detailuser it has two field one is name and other is phone ok i sucessfully inserted data and everything find then tried to analyse the security so typed in the textfield like  `<script>alert ('hello');</script>` it also sucessfully inserted into database i want to avoid this can any one help me view page containing html form is 
view page

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{!!url('addno')!!}"
 method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">      
       <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="title">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10"> 
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="name">
              <p class="errors">{!!$errors->first('name')!!}</p>
             </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="content">Phone</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
         <input type="text"class="form-control" id="content" name="phone"></input>
         <p class="errors">@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)<div>{{ $error }}</div>@endforeach</p>
      </div>
    </div>                                      
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-9">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
       </div>
     </div>
  </form>
```

route

```
Route::post('/addno','Admin\AdminController@addNo');
```

controller function

```
public function addNo(Request $request)
    {
        $det =$request->all();
        $rules = array('name' => 'required','phone' => 'required|numeric|is_ten');
        $validator = Validator::make($det,$rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) 
        {
            return Redirect::to('/addno')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }
        else
        {
            $bulletin = new Smsdetail;
            $bulletin->name = $request->name;
            $bulletin->phone= $request->phone;
            if($bulletin->save())
            {
                Session::flash('sucess', 'details added sucessfully'); 
                return Redirect::to('addno');
            }
            else
            {
                Session::flash('sucess', 'somthing went wrong check this phone no is previously added'); 
                return Redirect::to('addno');
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation) is what you are looking for

Comment: @DavidDomain this helpful and i also want know how can i perform mysql_real_escape_string operation in laravel